# Google Maps Marker doesn't show with List<LatLng>

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-layout, google-maps-markers

I do not understand why the map does not create marker using a `List<LatLng>` as follows:

```
protected void updateMapContents() {
 mGoogleMap.clear();
 if(myList.getList() != null && myList.getList().length > 0) {
     LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
     for (int i = 0; i < myList.getList().size(); i++) {
         mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myList.getList().get(i)));
         builder.include(myList.getList().get(i));
         Log.e("Position List:", " " + i + myList.getList().get(i));
     }
     LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
     int padding = 0;
     CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
     mGoogleMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
 }
}
```

This is logcat message:

> E/Position List::  0 lat/lng: (44.49,11.34)

The strange thing is that it all works with single marker, with array of LatLng also, I can not explain why with List this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've missed a check in `onMapReady()` method, so if I work with `List` it doesn't call `updateMapContents()`

That's all.